# Zeppelin table view converts strings to numbers

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm using Zeppelin 0.8.0 and I have an issue where the zeppelin table view is converting strings to numbers. In the following code snippet the data frame contains the string "007". This is displayed correctly when using the df.show method. However the z.show method seems to convert the string to number and just displays "7".

```
%spark
val df = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(List("007")).toDF("bond")
df.show
z.show(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Described bug was fixed in 0.8.1.

0.8.1 was already released.